# methodnotallowedhttpexception in routecollection.php line 218

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I know this is duplicate problem. Still I'm not able to correct this problem so can anyone help?

Routes.php

```
   Route::post('/form-submit',[
   'uses' => 'UserController@formSubmit',
   'as' => 'f.submit',
]);
```

UserController.php

```
public function formSubmit() #form-submit
{
   echo"Form Submit Method";
}
```

test_view.php

```
@extends('Layout.master')
@section('Content')
 {!! Form::open([
         'route' => 'f.submit', 'method' => 'post'
 ]) !!}
  {!! Form::test('username') !!}
  {!! Form::submit('submit')!!}
 {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

If I'm using get method for this code. then directly it is showing `Form Submit Method` and if I'm using post method then it is showing above error

Comment: I've never used Laravel so you might be doing something advanced. Anyways, according to https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing I am finding no examples which are passing an array into the second parameter. The second parameter is supposed to be a callback so you either need an anonymous function or the name of an accessible function within the scope.

Comment: It would be in your best interest to specify which Laravel version you are using...

Comment: `Route::post('/form-submit',
   'UserController@formSubmit'
   
);`
I tried this one also even with anonymous function.

Comment: Laravel 5.2 version

Comment: Well that's frustrating. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes shows array usage but https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes does not. Good luck

Comment: it's not helping. Can you promote this problem?

Comment: I believe you might not understand how this site works. The fact that you have a problem does not matter at all; nobody cares. This is not some problem solving service. Go pay a real web developer if you need a problem solved. People volunteer time here and will pay attention to questions which might interest them. So, as you can see, nobody is interested in your question and nobody can promote your problem anyways. If you have enough reputation then you can set a bounty which might attract attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a csrf token along the request within the form.

Comment: still it is same.

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
 //change '/form-submit' to 'f.submit'
    Route::post('/f.submit',[
       'uses' => 'UserController@formSubmit',
       'as' => 'f.submit',
    ])
```

and add csrf token also

Comment: post method is not working showing above error. and if i'm using get method then it is directly showing me "Form Submit Method". I tried ur code also but it is same.

Comment: @Code Demon can you give me any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting directly "Form Submit Method" rather than it should open test_view form. I have a solution for it using POST or GET method.

```
    Route::post('/form-submit',['
        'uses' => 'UserController@formSubmit'
        'as' => 'f.submit'
  ']});
```

But POST method still not working.